# Linux: Using pipe to send the information in between the processes

Tags: c, linux, pipe

The pipe is created with fd[] and fd1[]. I am writing with the pipes. Taking two pipes gave me error as i was referencing to STDIN_FILENO, so i deleted it. I just used the pipe to read and write. Now it is still not reading from the pipe. Pipe with file descriptor fd[] works. but the fd1[] does not.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv)
    {

    int fd[2]; 
    pid_t childpid;
    pipe(fd);
    int fd2[2];
    pipe(fd2);
    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int array2[5] = {11,12,13,14,15};
    //fprintf(stderr,"size%ld",sizeof(int));

    //char buffer[111];
    int *subarr1;

    int buffer_num;
    int status;

    if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nProcess:%d Parent:%d",getpid(),getppid());

        //dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]); //read end
        write(fd[1],array,100);
        close(fd[1]);
        //execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
        perror("The exec of ls failed\n");

            if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
             {
                 fprintf(stderr,"\nProcess:%d Parent:%d",getpid(),getppid());

                //dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd2[0]); //read end
                write(fd2[1],array2,sizeof(array2));
                close(fd2[1]);
                //execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
                perror("The exec of ls failed\n");
            }
            else
            {// parent 
                wait(NULL);
            }
    }
        else {
                wait(&status);
                fprintf(stderr,"\nTHis is parent");
                subarr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(5));
                fprintf(stderr,"\nProcess:%d Parent:%d",getpid(),getppid());

            //dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);

            int j;
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                read(fd[0],&buffer_num,sizeof(int));
                subarr1[j] = buffer_num;
                //printf("%s",buffer);

            }

            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"\n%d\n",subarr1[j]);
            }

            close(fd[0]);//read end


            //dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            buffer_num = 0;

            close(fd2[1]);
            //read(fd2[0],&buffer_num,100);

            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                read(fd2[0],&buffer_num,sizeof(int));
                subarr1[j] = buffer_num;
                //printf("%s",buffer);

            }

            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"\n%d\n",subarr1[j]);
            }
            //fprintf(stderr, "\nThis is second pipe%s", buffer);
            close(fd2[0]);


        /*//printf("\nAAAAAAAA%s\n",buffer);
            dup2(fd2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd2[1]);
        printf("\nAAAAAAAA%s\n",buffer);

            read(fd2[0],buffer,100);
            printf("%s",buffer);
            close(fd2[0]);//read end
        printf("\nAAAAAAAA%s\n",buffer);

    */
            //execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", "-n", NULL);
            perror("The exec of sort failed\n");
        }

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could improve your question. Give more context

Comment: I hope you checked the returned values from the calls to `pipe()` to assure the operations were successful.

Comment: To me, the posted code looks ok.   Could you post the first and second child code?   At least the parts that setup/write to the pipe(s).  And perhaps the code that calls fork()/exec..() to setup the two children

Comment: I have uploaded the codes. Sorry for being late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call:

```
read(fd2[0],&buffer_num,100);
```

tries to read 100 bytes into memory starting at the local (int) variable `buffer`, so overwrites whatever else is on the stack after it, smashing the stack and causing undefined behavior (probably crashing at some point).

You have similar problems with your `write` calls, writing 100 bytes from objects that are much smaller, but those likely only write garbage you then ignore, rather than causing a crash (though that is likewise undefined behavior).

Comment: I changed the code read(fd2[0],&buffer_num,100); to read(fd2[0],&buffer_num,sizeof(int)); but still it doesn't give me the value from the buffer.

Comment: You code above seems to work fine when I compile it (ignoring a bunch of warnings)...